# JavaScript, create an Array with random 10 numbers from 1 to 10, Array length 9 elements. Find the number what leftover?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, numbers

I search **everywhere** here but couldn't find the answer...only some pieces of it..
I got an interview question...
You have an array and it's **array.length=9**. You have **10 numbers**, from 1 to 10. Put those numbers **randomly** to Array. How to **find/return** the number what **leftover** and not got to the Array.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
var chosen = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 9; i ++){
  var index = Math.floor((Math.random() * numbers.length) + 1)-1;
  chosen.push(numbers[index]);
  numbers.splice(index, 1);
  }
document.write(JSON.stringify(chosen)+"<br>");
document.write(numbers);
```

Comment: OK... can we create the Array first from random numbers, and after find what number was not included and print the created Array and the number?...Thx

Comment: Thank you, almost as I did...:-)

Comment: @ira2015 if this answer helped you, would you mind accepting it by clicking on the green check mark next to my answer? It gives you reputation too :)

Answer (score 0):

using `array.indexOf()` method you can do it.
first creat random array `arr` then do this:

```
 for(var i=1;i<=10;i++){
       if(arr.indexOf(i)==-1){
           console.log(i+'is not in the array');
           return i;
        }
    }
```